# LXLE- minimize button closes application

Tags: window-manager

When I click the minimize button (top rgt of window bar, "-", next to "+ x" ), the program window closes completely, as opposed to minimizes to the panel. I don't recall this issue when I first installed a couple days ago, but I've wrestled with a number of things over a week or so, and I can't recall what the last thing I did before the issue appeared.

As far as I can tell, the program is not running and minimized to the panel. If it's a browser, there are no tabs open in the restored window (tho there were tabs open in the window I minimized). If it's a text editor, there is no file open in the restored window (tho a file was open in the window I minimized). And it takes time to open the program - not like restoring a window.

I'm new to Linux / LXLE so please include basic things to look at. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a panel item issue.

I removed the "Application Launch Bar" and
added a "Application Launch and Task Bar" - this displays minimized tasks.

I found this by using <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>, which revealed that the tasks were in fact just minimized, not closed, altho I could not see them in the Panel because of the panel items I had set.